# EntityFramework создает множество записей в бд

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Пишу программу для учета поставщиков, и заказов у данных поставщиков с использованием Entity Framework Code First.

Одновременно с созданием заказа, создается новый поставщик с данным заказом, то есть в БД есть поставщик с заказом и поставщик без заказа, если создать ещё один заказ, то создастся ещё один поставщик с данным заказом.

**Классы:**

*`Поставщик`:*

```
public class Contractor
{
    public int ContractorId { get; set; }
    public string ContractorName { get; set; }
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ContractorName;
    }
}
```

*`Заказ`:*

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PositionsQty> PositionsQty { get; set; }
    public decimal Sum { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public Byte[] InvoiceScan { get; set; }
    public Byte[] ClosingDocScan { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public int ContractorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contractor Contractor { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Счет №: " + InvoiceNumber + " от " + OrderDate.Day + "/" + OrderDate.Month + "/" + OrderDate.Year;
    }
}
```

*Создание `Заказа`:*

```
 private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db = new ContractorContext())
        {
            Order order = new Order();
            if(InvoiceNumberBox.Text != null)
            order.InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumberBox.Text;
            order.DeliveryDate = DeliveryDatePick.SelectedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
            order.OrderDate = OrderDatePick.SelectedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
            if(InvoiceSumBox.Text != null)
            order.Sum = Decimal.Parse(InvoiceSumBox.Text.Replace('.',','));
            order.Contractor = _contractor;
            order.ContractorId = _contractor.ContractorId;
            order.PositionsQty = new List<PositionsQty>();
            foreach (PositionsQty item in OrderPositions.Items)
            {
                order.PositionsQty.Add(item);
            }
            if (_contractor.Orders != null)
            {
                _contractor.Orders.Add(order);
            }
            else
            {
                _contractor.Orders = new List<Order> {order};
            }
            //db.Contractors.AddOrUpdate(_contractor);
            db.Orders.AddOrUpdate(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Объект `_contractor` передаётся из другой формы.

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

объекты `order` и `_contractor` находятся в разных экземплярах контекста `ContractorContext`. Чтобы не плодить дубли не заполняйте поле `order.Contractor`, вполне достаточно указать `order.ContractorId`.

Comment: Убрал заполнения поля и всё работает как надо, спасибо

Comment: @ajlewa а может стоит добавить проверку исключающую возможность дублирования, проверено если не будете отлавливать такие ситуации, то это(дублирование) обязательно случится

Answer (score 1):

А у Вас в структуре базы для таблицы  Contractor первичный ключ создался как ContractorId? Возможно Вам поможет явное указание ключей для Entity Framevork, попробуйте так.

Для поставщика:

```
public class Contractor
{
    [Key]
    public int ContractorId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Для заказа:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    ...

    [ForeignKey("Contractor ")]
    public int ContractorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Contractor Contractor { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Первичный ключ в бд сгенерировался правильно, проблема решена, но спасибо за ответ